# Eclipse ADT automatically creates a fragment for Activities. Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-activity

I vaguely understand what fragments are used for. However, I don't understand why ADT seems to suggest that we should ALWAYS use them. I am aware that I can simply delete the `fragment layout`, as well as the code in `Activity` for the fragment. But is it ACTUALLY recommended to use fragments all the time? What are the benefits of not deleting it?

Is there even a point of an Activity having a single fragment? What is the difference with it having no fragments at all?

Additionally, how do you know whether to create multiple fragments in one Activity, multiple Activities with a single or zero fragments or a combination of Activities and fragments?

For example, if you have a `Terms and Conditions` button in your Activity, and you want it to open a screen containing a document listing the terms and conditions, should I be starting a new Activity for that? Or should I just move a fragment containing this content to the front?

Comment: it is not eclipse. it is adt

Comment: ADT is a plugin for Eclipse, but I see your point.

Comment: adt stays for android development tool and can be used with or without eclipse/

Comment: From this website (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html), I quote `ADT (Android Developer Tools) is a plugin for Eclipse that provides a suite of tools that are integrated with the Eclipse IDE.`. The semantics aren't really relevant to the question, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Fragments is how modern apps are developed today.
Some of the benefits are a better performance when switching content (lets say 2 fragments)
because you are not leaving the current Activity.

Also, apps with swipe tabs (for example) are built with an Activity as a container and Fragments as the content itself.

Other benefit is that you can do much more with one activity, distributing work between the fragments. Each Fragment have its own Layout and therefore its own components, so maintaining the code and keeping organized is easier.

Eclipse does this way as suggesting a start point. You can totally ignore this and start from scratch. And that's all.

I suggest you to keep the Fragment to start getting used to it. Even if there is just one.
And, if later you need to work more with that Activity, it will be easier to add new features by creating a new Fragment, without modifying your previous code.

Good luck.